# High availability website using IIS / windows server

Tags: iis, load-balancing, windows-server-2016, high-availability, iis-10

My website is currently running on a single windows server 2016 machine with IIS and SQL server 2017. Every time there's a windows update, new hardware install, etc., my site goes offline.

My goal is to keep the website running normally (read and write db) even when one of the machines is offline.
I have done some research and have come across technologies such as: fail over clustering, load balancing, etc. but not sure where to apply them

My current understanding is that I need 4 machines (2 for IIS and 2 for SQL Server) and at the each level I need:

- OS: network load balancing
- IIS: ??
- SQL Server: Always On availability group

A lot of these articles I found are from 2009, 2010, not sure if they still apply or there's anything better now

I'm new setting up a high availability web server. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you decide to switch to Azure Stack, those articles still apply to you.

Comment: So is my understanding correct? I need to set up network load balancing on the OS level and Always On availability group for SQL server